# PyCharm on MacOS (Monterey, Arm) using wrong python interpretter

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm 2022.1 on MacOS uses the wrong interpreter although I configured it with Python 3.10 in Preferences->Project->Python Interpreter and have the right Python (3.10) version in my system. (I start it from an Rosetta Terminal)

I don't know were to configure it else because there is nowhere the (old) Python Interpreter (3.9) for PyCharm configured.

Answer (score 0):

The problem laid in "numpy" and "PIL" which I imported to my application.
Maybe, they were originally compiled for python3.9 and for that reason not any more compatible and caused the problem and the complaining about python3.9

But fact is, after excluding those tools, I could start my application